# Javascript if cookie exist apply css

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I want to apply css through javascript if cookie `xxx`exist - code:

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
var kuki = document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_name=xxx');
alert(kuki);
if (kuki != -1)
{
document.getElementById("ads-back").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("ffield").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("bcd").style.display = "none";
}
else { setCookie(xxx, 1, 1) }
</script>
```

The problem is that I always receiving -1 it should after seting cookie `setCookie(xxx, 1, 1)` get different value?

Comment: I don’t think you are setting the string cookie_name=xxx within the cookie.  Your setcookie function sets xxx=1.

Answer (score 0):

> setCookie(`xxx`, 1, 1)

As you are setting cookie name with xxx variable and finding it with cookie_name as below that is the issue..try to find the index of cookie actual name set then it will work.

> var kuki = document.cookie.indexOf('`cookie_name`=xxx');

Answer (score 0):

To save cookie you have to use following format

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";expires=" + expires + ";";
```

To get saved cookies you have to use following both ways because if you have saved more than one cookie your cookie may not be the first element of the cookie array so you have to check both 'cookie_name=xxx' and 
' cookie_name=xxx'

```
var kuki1 = document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_name=xxx');
var kuki2 = document.cookie.indexOf(' cookie_name=xxx');
```